# PySpark SQL: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression:

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I a trying to create a new column in my `test` dataframe using values from another dataframe called `train`. Below is a snapshot. In the `train` dataframe, The value in the first row under the column `aml_freq_a` is the number of times `v` appears in column `a`. Similarly, the `42` under `aml_freq_b` is the number of times `l` appears in `b`. The `['aml_freq_a', 'aml_freq_b', 'aml_freq_c']` are basically frequency columns.

```
>>> train.show(5)

+---+---+---+----------+----------+----------+                                  
|  a|  b|  c|aml_freq_a|aml_freq_b|aml_freq_c|
+---+---+---+----------+----------+----------+
|  v|  l|  l|        56|        42|        29|
|  u|  g|  l|        47|        46|        29|
|  s|  g|  l|        28|        46|        29|
|  v|  m|  l|        56|        33|        29|
|  h|  m|  l|        44|        33|        29|
+---+---+---+----------+----------+----------+
```

In the `test` dataset has columns `['a', 'b', 'c']`. Here, I need to add the frequency columns - `['aml_freq_a', 'aml_freq_b', 'aml_freq_c']`.

```
>>> test.show(5)
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  w|  j|  c|
|  a|  g|  w|
|  s|  d|  i|
|  g|  j|  r|
|  r|  b|  u|
+---+---+---+
```

To do this, I wrote subqueries that join `train` and `test` on `a,b` and,`c`.

```
query = "select test.*,
  (select aml_freq_a from test left join train on test.a = train.a),
  (select aml_freq_b from test left join train on test.b = train.b),
  (select aml_freq_c from ten left join train on test.c = train.c)
from test"

train.createTempView('train')
test.createTempView('test')
```

`spark.sql(query)` runs fine but when I call `show()` on it it returns me the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression:
```

What does this mean? Initially I thought there was something wrong with my query but I validated my query [here](https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/) and there's nothing wrong here. What am I not seeing here?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us the test data frame?

Comment: @MichailN, I have edited to include it.

Comment: Use dataframe join and do the joins one after the other. More than one joined row comes for each row from the test dataframe so it is impossible to create a dataframe like that.
http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join

Comment: Also spark.sql(query) "runs" fine because it has not yet run. Spark is lazy evaluated which means that everything is computed only when an action is triggered (like show) See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38027877/spark-transformation-why-its-lazy-and-what-is-the-advantage

Comment: @MichailN yes, yes. I am aware of the lazy eval. I always call the `show` method on all my dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your attempt, `(select aml_freq_a from test left join train on test.a = train.a)` would return a `dataframe` i.e. *multiple rows* which can't be used as a select argument as `"select test.*, (select aml_freq_a from test left join train on test.a = train.a),...`

Correct query would be as below

```
query = "select test.* from " \
            "(select test.*, aml_freq_a from " \
                "(select test.*, aml_freq_b from " \
                    "(select test.*, aml_freq_c from test " \
                "left join train on test.c = train.c) as test " \
            "left join train on test.b = train.b)  as test " \
        "left join train on test.a = train.a) as test"
```

If the header is required in following format

```
+---+---+---+----------+----------+----------+
|a  |b  |c  |aml_freq_a|aml_freq_b|aml_freq_c|
+---+---+---+----------+----------+----------+
```

then

```
query = "select test.* from " \
            "(select test.*, aml_freq_c from " \
                "(select test.*, aml_freq_b from " \
                    "(select test.*, aml_freq_a from test " \
                "left join train on test.a = train.a) as test " \
            "left join train on test.b = train.b)  as test " \
        "left join train on test.c = train.c) as test"
```

You can do it in much simpler and safer way **using dataframe api**

```
test.join(train.select('a', 'aml_freq_a'), ['a'], 'left') \
    .join(train.select('b', 'aml_freq_b'), ['b'], 'left') \
    .join(train.select('c', 'aml_freq_c'), ['c'], 'left')
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I have to go with the sql one over here because this part goes into a function and using sql gives more flexibility in cases where I have more than three variables. 

Apart from the being easy to understand is there any other benefit of using the dataframe API? Also, you mention `simpler and safer way`. What do you mean by `safer` here?

Comment: I meant was type safety. :)

Answer (score 1):

It means that

- At least one of the correlated subqueries you use returns more than one match.
- While Spark supports only one value returned for each row (i.e. correlated subqueries have to be aggregated).