# How to avoid doing the same transformations multiple times in Spark DataFrames?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a raw Spark Dataframe `DF`. Let's assume a simple scenario in which I want to preprocess and transform it in a few ways, and then finally draw two plots.

My pseudocode would look like this:

```
DF = spark.read.csv('foo.csv')
DF = preprocess(DF)

result_1 = some_aggregations(DF).toPandas()
result_2 = some_different_aggregations(DF).toPandas()
```

Now, If I understood correctly, e.g. from [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38027877/spark-transformation-why-its-lazy-and-what-is-the-advantage), then:

- `preprocess(DF)` is *not* actually run in line 2.
- The disadvantage is that `preprocess(DF)` is run *twice* - once for `result_1`, and once for `result_2`.

Is this disadvantage (redundant/multiple computation) a generally accepted disadvantage of the Spark way? Or am I processing my data inefficiently?

Comment: For such cases, to avoid recomputation, we use `cache()`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28983767/7045987).

Comment: `DF = preprocess(DF).persist()` is what you're looking for.