# Error using filter on column value with Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Please refer to my sample code below:

`sampleDf` -> my sample Scala dataframe that I want to filter on 2 columns `startIPInt` and `endIPInt`.

```
var row = sampleDf.filter("startIPInt <=" + ip).filter("endIPInt >= " + ip)
```

I now want to view the content of this row. 
The following takes barely a sec to execute but does not show me the contents of this row object:

```
println(row)
```

But this code takes too long to execute:

```
row.show()
```

So my question is how should I view the content of this row object? Or is there any issue with the way I am filtering my dataframe?

My initial approach was to use filter as mentioned here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#filter(java.lang.String)

According to that, the following line of code gives me an error about "overloaded method 'filter'":

```
var row = sampleDf.filter($"startIPInt" <= ip).filter($"endIPInt" >= ip)
```

Can anyone help me understand what is happening here? And which is the right and fastest way to filter and get content of a dataframe as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, using `filter` you don't really get a row/row object, you will get a new dataframe.

The reason `show` takes longer to execute is due to Spark being lazy. It will only compute transformations when an action is taken on the dataframe (see e.g. [Spark Transformation - Why its lazy and what is the advantage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38027877/spark-transformation-why-its-lazy-and-what-is-the-advantage)). Using `println` on a dataframe will not do anything and the filter transformations will not actually be computed. `show` on the other hand requires some computation which is why it's slower to execute.

Using

```
sampleDf.filter("startIPInt <=" + ip).filter("endIPInt >= " + ip)
```

and

```
sampleDf.filter($"startIPInt" <= ip).filter($"endIPInt" >= ip)
```

are equivalent and should give the same result as long as you have imported spark implicits (for use of the `$` notation).