# Managing multiple dataframes in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am a novice to PySpark. In my implementation, I have used multiple dataframes. Out of these certain are intermediate dataframes that will not be used later on the code. How can I handle them? I am facing GC OverHead and memory issues. Any help is appreciated

```
df_total_ch=df_agg.groupby('circle','vendor','zone','nss_id','category','sub_category','node_model','node_name','OAF').agg(func.count('OAF').alias('total_Card_count'))

df_total_ch=df_total_ch.groupby('circle','vendor','zone','nss_id','category','sub_category','node_model','node_name').agg(func.count("*").alias('total_Card_count'))

df_new=df_agg.join(df_total_ch,on=['circle','vendor','zone','nss_id','category','sub_category','node_model','node_name'],how='left_outer')

base_df=df_new.select ('eventtime','circle','vendor','zone','nss_id','category','sub_category','node_model','node_name','OAF','temperature_event_count','temperature_weight','power_event_count','power_weight','hardware_event_count','hardware_weight','other_event_count','other_weight','housekeeping_event_count','housekeeping_weight')

base_df_final = base_df.groupby('eventtime','circle','vendor','zone','nss_id','category','sub_category','node_model','node_name','OAF').agg(func.sum('temperature_event_count').alias('temperature_event_count'),func.sum('temperature_weight').alias('temperature_weight'),func.sum('power_event_count').alias('power_event_count'),func.sum('power_weight').alias('power_weight'),func.sum('hardware_event_count').alias('hardware_event_count'),func.sum('hardware_weight').alias('hardware_weight'),func.sum('other_event_count').alias('other_event_count'),func.sum('other_weight').alias('other_weight'),func.sum('housekeeping_event_count').alias('housekeeping_event_count'),func.sum('housekeeping_weight').alias('housekeeping_weight'))

base_df_final=base_df_final.withColumn('hardware_flag',when(func.col('hardware_event_count') > 0,lit('Yes')).otherwise(lit('No')))
base_df_final=base_df_final.withColumn('power_flag',when(func.col('power_event_count') > 0,lit('Yes')).otherwise(lit('No')))
base_df_final=base_df_final.withColumn('temperature_flag',when(func.col('temperature_event_count') > 0,lit('Yes')).otherwise(lit('No')))
base_df_final=base_df_final.withColumn('others_flag',when(func.col('other_event_count') > 0,lit('Yes')).otherwise(lit('No')))
base_df_final=base_df_final.withColumn('housekeeping_flag',when(func.col('housekeeping_event_count') > 0,lit('Yes')).otherwise(lit('No')))

base_df_final.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("DFT.TBL_TX")
```

I get the below error

```
    base_df_final.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("DFT.TBL_TX")
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.3-1.cdh6.3.3.p0.1796617/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 775, in saveAsTable
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.3-1.cdh6.3.3.p0.1796617/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.3-1.cdh6.3.3.p0.1796617/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.3-1.cdh6.3.3.p0.1796617/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o482.saveAsTable.
: org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
   at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2261)
   at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
   at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4789)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.getCachedPlan(SessionCatalog.scala:141)
```

Comment: due to spark's lazy evaluation, none of these intermediate dataframes actually exist. you can think of these dataframes as only query plans. If you face memory issues, try using `select('*', col)` instead of `withColumn(col)` - that sometimes helps

Comment: Could you please elaborate on using this "select('*',col) in my current code

Comment: @stacktesting for example, the first withcolumn line can be replaced with `base_df_final = base_df_final.select('*', when(func.col('hardware_event_count') > 0,lit('Yes')).otherwise(lit('No')).alias('hardware_flag'))`. similarly for other lines of withcolumn.

Comment: I tried the above. But still  facing GC overhead issues

Answer (score 1):

Spark transformations are lazily evaluated. All transformations are added to dataframe but not applied yet. When you call action methods like show(), count(), write(), transformations are applied at that moment.

So, you are applying lots of transformations in chain to dataframe and assigning to new one. All transformations exist in each dataframe's history. you can view them by executing df.explain() method. You finally you obtain `base_df_final` dataframe and this df contains all the transformations above and ready to apply with action method write(). However, memory is not sufficient to do all the operations at the same time, so it should be separated into multiple operations.

You can consider writing and reading same dataframe temporarily somewhere between transformations. This will apply all transformations to df and clears the history of it. So you use less memory for two different(or more) actions and use disk space temporarily

[Spark Transformation - Why its lazy and what is the advantage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38027877/spark-transformation-why-its-lazy-and-what-is-the-advantage)

Comment: I tried the above . But still the code is running into memory issues

Comment: 1/ Can you share error message? 2/ how big is your data and what about your RAM? You may consider more frequent write/read operations or repartition your dataframes first. If partition size is high, you probably reduce your `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` configuration

Comment: I have added intermediate read/write actions. Also, when data is present in spark and I am able to perform a "count" action. But it is failing only while loading into final hive table. I have upadted the original question with the error as well.

Comment: We have 256GB RAM. Also, I tried to set "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" to values "10" and "100". But still it throws the same error