# Databricks spark sql, fact query, slow at showing data

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

using the following example on a large table:

`pages = spark.sql('select * from table xx')`, I found that the query runs in seconds, but as soon as I want to see the data with `pages.show(n=10)` it takes minutes to get the data to have a sample of that data. What is happening under the hood to be so slow.

the SQL (`spark.sql`) command takes < 1 second but the `pages.show(n=10)` takes minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark does lazy evaluation so it won't start actually executing the command (e.g. `select * from table xx`) until an 'action' is call (e.g. `.show()`, `.write` or `display()` in Databricks).

The part that is running <1 sec is the evaluation—it's checking to see if the command *can* be executed, but not actually executing until an action.

Related reads on Transformation vs Actions with Spark:

- https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/spark-transformations-actions-lazy-evaluation-mohammad-younus-jameel/
- [Spark Transformation - Why is it lazy and what is the advantage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38027877/spark-transformation-why-is-it-lazy-and-what-is-the-advantage)